# Capacitor: how to hide splash screen on WebView loaded?

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor

I've faced with too long WebView loading on my device. After splash screen is hide by default I still can see black screen about a couple of seconds and only after that I can see my app view. At the time when black screen become to normal I can see log message "WebView loaded". I think this is a pretty good moment to hide my splash screen manually.
Ho to do that? How to catch "WebView loaded" event?
Thanks!